# Type 'UIButton' has no member 'sender'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

If 'sender' is of type UIButton in the function's argument, why can't it be explicitly shown to inherit from the UIButton class using the dot operator? Does it have something to do with Swift's type-inference feature, or is it wrong to type 'UIButton.sender' in this situation? I'm new to OOP and still figuring out how properties inherit from classes (e.g. UIButton) in Swift.

```
@IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = UIButton.sender.currentTitle!  // ERROR unless UIButton is removed
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
        let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
        display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
    } else {
        display.text = digit
    }
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
}
```

Comment: `let digit = sender.currentTitle!` most likely... but the force unwrapping here still makes me raising an eyebrow.

Comment: Thanks! To avoid force unwrapping, would this be a situation to use optional binding? I've heard that if something is guaranteed to be set at some point, then force unwrapping could be fine, albeit risky as you alluded to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some fundamental knowledge about swift. The dot operator in your case does not "explicitly shown to inherit from the UIButton class". The dot operator can access a property, method or embedded element in your class.

If you wanted your code `UIButton.sender` to work you could write something like:

```
extension UIButton {
    static var sender: UIButton { return UIButton() }
}
```

Not that this makes any sense. It will make your code work but it will generate a new button and have nothing to do with your `sender`.

Inheritance in your case is already explicitly done in the method argument `touchDigit(sender: UIButton)` but could as well be removed by writing `touchDigit(sender: Any)`. Now in this case `sender` may be anything. To use it as `UIButton` you need to typecast it like `sender as! UIButton`:

```
@IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: Any) {
    let digit = (sender as! UIButton).currentTitle!
```

This may then crash if you call it with anything but a button, So for instance if you did:

```
func doSomething() {
    self.touchDigit(sender: "some text")
}

@IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: Any) {
    let digit = (sender as! UIButton).currentTitle!
```

Call to `doSomething` will crash your app at `(sender as! UIButton)` since sender is not an `UIButton`. So what you do in such case is check for type like:

```
func doSomething() {
    self.touchDigit(sender: "some text")
}

@IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: Any) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        let digit = button.currentTitle!
            if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
                let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
                display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
            } else {
                display.text = digit
            }
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
        }
    } else if let text = sender as? String {
        display.text = text
    }
}
```

I hope this clears a few things for you.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Also, on the line "if let button = sender as? UIButton", could 'as!' alternatively be used when casting sender as a UIButton?

Comment: @JCoder No. You will get a compile time error because then expression is not optional. So the difference explicitly would be: `let button: UIButton? = sender as? UIButton` or `let button: UIButton = sender as! UIButton`. Since the second is not optional (has no `?`) you can not continue with `if let button = button`.

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` is a class and `sender` is an instance variable of `UIButton`. So You can't access properties inside instance variable via Class(`UIButton`).

If `UIButton` has static variables or class functions, you can access it using class(ex: UIButton.description()).

Also in below function,

```
func touchDigit(sender: UIButton)
```

`sender` is a parameter of the function and `UIButton` is the type of `sender` parameter.

You can learn more about Swift functions here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html